# I want my program to run for a specific amount of time

Tags: python

I am making a face recognition program and I defined a for loop to check accuracy but i want to terminate my program after 5 seconds (means if it couldn't detect any face after 5 seconds it will run the else statement).can anyone help please

```
            if (accuracy >= 55):
            id = names[id]
            accuracy = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - accuracy))

        else:
            id = "unknown"
            accuracy = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - accuracy))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5, y-5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(accuracy), (x+5, y+h-5),
                    font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
    if k == 2:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use time library to save a global variable with the start time of your program:

```
start_time = time.time()
```

for each iteration do:

```
if (time.time() - start_time) > 5:
    print("No faces detected")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time as time
startTime = time.time()
while time.time() - startTime <= 5:
            if (accuracy >= 55):
            id = names[id]
            accuracy = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - accuracy))

        else:
            id = "unknown"
            accuracy = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - accuracy))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5, y-5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(accuracy), (x+5, y+h-5),
                    font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
    if k == 2:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could user a Timer() to set a flag after a given amount of time and check that flag inside your program iterations:

```
from threading import Timer

timeout  = []                                # timeout flag
runTime  = Timer(5,lambda:timeout.append(1)) # timer setup (5 seconds)
runTime.start()                              # start countdown

for i in range(10**1000):
    # do some work
    if timeout:                 # check flag (can be multiple places)
        print("ran up to ",i) 
        break                   # break out of iterations

ran up to  51970836
```

*This approach adds less overhead to your process than checking a time.time() delta.  It also makes the time check simpler and more efficient, which will be advantageous if you have several nested loops to break or multiple 'clean' interruption locations.*